# onPostExcute executed before doInbackground in asynctask

Tags: android, api, asynchronous, android-asynctask, ui-thread

i have `asynctask` which i call api inside `doInBackGround` and i'm using *okhtpp* and then i enqueue the request actually the enqueue does not block the main thread so the `asyncTask` execute `onPostExcute()` directly how to fix this

`onPostExcute()` i show new view but when excute `asyncTask` it opens new view directly before the api request is done
what is the best way to show the view after api request is done

```
public class makeTheRequest extends AsyncTask<String ,String,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                //show failed
            }


            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                //show response
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        super.onPostExecute(unused);
        rootView.addView(alternateLayout);
    }
}
```

and im calling the class here

```
if (Q.isEmpty()){
                    
    Toast.makeText(activty.this,"empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} else{
    new startRequest().execute(Q);
}
```

this is code sample not the full code did this cuz the full code is too large

Comment: `enqueue()` = Asynchronous, `execute()` = Synchronous.

Comment: `doInBackground extends AsyncTask` ?? Please dont name your task like that as doInBackground is a private member of an async task as you know. Very confusing. Unteadable code in this way.

Comment: Please show how you call your asynctask.

Comment: You should not use an asynctask here. Not needed. You can do without.